How to save null value into Laravel date column format?
I am having trouble creating or updating data in the 'valid_to' column with null value. However Laravel always uses CURRENT_DATE as the default which is irrelevant to my needs because I need the data to be null.
I have made sure that:

Column table in database is already nullable.
The column does not set any default value other than NULL.
The Laravel model does not modify null.
There are no triggers or mutators that set valid_to to the current
date.
The payload value that I received was indeed null, I have debugged and logged it.

Here my controller code:
$trainingsData = [
            'category_id'   => $request->category_id,
            'trainer_id'    => $request->trainer_id,
            'valid_from'    => $request->valid_from,
        ];
        if (isset($request->valid_to)) {
            $trainingsData['valid_to'] = $request->valid_to;
        }
        $participant->participantTrainings()->create($trainingsData);
        $participant->save();

and here my code in model:
protected $guarded = [];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array<string, string>
 */
protected $casts = [
    'participant_id' => 'integer',
    'category_id' => 'integer',
    'trainer_id' => 'integer',
    'valid_from' => 'date:Y-m-d',
];

Someone please help me.

Is there an error message?

Specify what error you are getting during the code execution ?

Have you tried explicitly setting it to null if not provided. In your $trainingsData array 'valid_to' => $request->valid_to ?? null

@JorisJ1 there is no error, the data is saved with Current Date data by default. I want the data to be null

@noah1400 I've done it, but the result is still the same.

There must be some other place where that CURRENT_DATE is set. When I try to reproduce your problem with Participant::create(['category_id' => 1, 'trainer_id' => 2, 'valid_from' => null]); the field in the table becomes NULL, as it should. Is anything special happening within participantTrainings()?

Check your column definition in the database (check the actual schema, not your migrations). It sounds like the database is setting the value to the current timestamp when you pass in null. If using mysql, your column could be defined with DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Or, if the explicit_defaults_for_timestamp system variable is disabled, the first timestamp field in the table will have both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP automatically assigned if neither is specified explicitly.
